# How to fill the blank spaces in first column with value obtained from previous non-blank line?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

```
Sample Input:
James  account
       note
       money
Ruby   account
       money
Taylor account
       note
Rob    money


Desired Output:

James  account
James  note
James  money
Ruby   account
Ruby   money
Taylor account
Taylor note
Rob    money
```

As you notice in the above output, all the blank spaces in first-column are filled with value obtained from previous non-empty line. I am using KSH, Linux x86. I prefer awk, sed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
awk 'NF>1 {x=$1; print; next} {print x,$1}' Input
James  account
James note
James money
Ruby   account
Ruby money
Taylor account
Taylor note
Rob    money
```

If you want to prettify the alignment of the output, pipe it through `column -t`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NF == 1 { $2 = $1; $1 = col1 } { col1 = $1; print }' file
James  account
James note
James money
Ruby   account
Ruby money
Taylor account
Taylor note
Rob    money
```

If the number of whitespace-delimited fields on the current line is one (`NF == 1`), then move the contents of the first field into the second (which is empty), then assign the value saved in `col1` to the first field.

For all lines, save the value of the first field into `col1` and print.

Answer (score 0):

Using cut and tr:

```
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line
do
    if printf -- '%s\n' "$line" | grep -E -q '^[[:blank:]]'
    then
        # is blank
        word="$(printf -- '%s\n' "$line" | tr -d '[:blank:]')"
        printf -- '%s %s\n' "$prefix" "$word"
    else
        # is not blank
        prefix="$(printf -- '%s\n' "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
        printf -- '%s\n' "$line" | tr -s ' '
    fi
done < file
```

Output:

```
James account
James note
James money
Ruby account
Ruby money
Taylor account
Taylor note
Rob money
```

Then, it can be padded with `column -t`, [as mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/461626/301259).

Alternatively, without `column`:

```
length=0
while read -r line
do
    cur_length="$(printf -- '%s\n' "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | wc -c)"
    [ "$cur_length" -gt "$length" ] && length="$cur_length"
done < file

while IFS=$'\n' read -r line
do
    if printf -- '%s\n' "$line" | grep -E -q '^[[:blank:]]'
    then
        # is blank
        word="$(printf -- '%s\n' "$line" | tr -d '[:blank:]')"

        printf -- "%-${length}s%s\n" "$prefix" "$word"
    else
        # is not blank
        prefix="$(printf -- '%s\n' "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | \
          tr -d '[:blank:]')"

        suffix="$(printf -- '%s\n' "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | \
          tr -d '[:blank:]')"

        printf -- "%-${length}s%s\n" "$prefix" "$suffix"
    fi
done < file
```

Output:

```
James  account
James  note
James  money
Ruby   account
Ruby   money
Taylor account
Taylor note
Rob    money
```

Answer (score 0):

One way with `GNU sed` is as following:

```
sed -re '                       ;# invoke GNU sed with extended regex engine
    /\S\s+\S/N                  ;# append the next line into the PS for multi-field lines
    s/^((\S+\s+).*\n)\s+/\1\2/  ;# stick the first two fields from 1st line to 2nd
    P;D                         ;# print multi-field line, & the 2nd line too now is multi-field
' input.file
```

**Output:**

```
James  account
James  note
James  money
Ruby   account
Ruby   money
Taylor account
Taylor note
Rob    money
```

**Constraints:**

1. The input with multi-field line mustn't begin with blanks/spaces.
2. GNU sed supporting extended regexes needed, although this code can be reworded to be POSIXly.